# Request method 'PUT' not supported] while redirecting to another endpoind

Tags: spring, redirect

```
  @PutMapping(value = {"/change-password"},
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public RedirectView changePassword(@RequestBody PasswordChangeDTO dto
    , HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws GIOException {
Boolean isChanged = service.changePassword(dto);

//i have tried all of those
// response.sendRedirect("login");
//        response.sendRedirect("/login");
//        return new RedirectView("login");
//        response.sendRedirect("login");
return null;
}
```

I have tried all of those code lines to make it redirect to **login** but it did not. This is login

```
  @GetMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false) String message) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityUtil.getAuthentication();
```

It can come here.

From front end, it comes as anonymous.

Like this;:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/change-password",
                data: stringifiedDTO,
```

I see values correctly and it changes password. But cant redirect. What can i do?

Comment: You are doing ajax, hence redirect will not redirect in the browsser but in the ajax request. You will need to handle it on the client as well (you will get the resulting HTML page). It also looks like you are hacking around Spring Security (with the login page controller).

Comment: If i use thymeleaf action, will it be same?

Comment: Then it is a regular form submit and the browser will handle the redirect.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. Is there any approach to send the DTO via thymeleaf action without using `requestparam`?

Comment: Why would you need request param? Instead of `@RequestBody` use `@ModelAttribute`.